# Proving recursively defined set and non recursively defined set are equal

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

**Question:**

Note: natural numbers start at $0$

Consider the recursively defined set $S$ $ \subset \mathbb{N}$:

$ 2 \in S$

If $ \ k \in S$ then $ \ k^{2} \in S$

If $ \ k \in S$ and $ \ k \ge 2$ then $ \ \frac{k}{2} \in S$

Also, condsider $ \  T = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} \ | \exists \ m \in \mathbb{N}, n = 2^{m}\}$

Prove $S = T$. Show $ \ S \subset T$ using structural induction and $ \ T \subset S$ using complete\strong induction.

**My attempt:**

To prove $ \ S \subset T$ we use structural induction.  In this part,we show that the base case of $S$ is in $T$, and that all elements generated using the recursive rules of S are also in T.

For clarity we define predicate $ P(n): n = 2^{m}$ for some $ \ m \in \mathbb{N}$

The base element of $ \ S$ is $2$ and $ 2 = 2^{1}$.

Now for the induction step there are two recursive rules.

First Rule:

Let $ k \in S$ and assume $P(k)$. Since $k = 2^{m}$ for some $ \ m \in \mathbb{N} \implies k^{2} = 2^{2m}.$ Let $ \ x = 2m$. Then $ \ k^{2} = 2^{x}$ for some $ \ x \in \mathbb{N}$.

Second Rule:

Suppose $ \ k \in S, k \ge 2$ and $ \ P(k)$ is true. Then, $ k = 2^{m}$ for some $ \ m \in \mathbb{N} \implies \frac{k}{2} = 2^{m-1}$. Let $ x = m-1$. Then $ \ \frac{k}{2} = 2^{x}$ for some $ \ x \in \mathbb{N}$

Have I proven this correctly using structural induction?

Also, I am not sure how to prove the other way using complete\strong induction. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the second condition meant to imply that 'if $k\in S$, $k$ is even'? (otherwise $k/2$ isn't necessarily defined).  If so, then there's a relatively straightforward way of showing that any member of $S$ must be a power of $2$.

Comment: This is exactly what question said. I have to show that every power of 2 which is in Set $ \ T$ is also in Set $ \ S$. In another words $ \ T \subseteq S$

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki Could you please show me how to do that using complete induction?

Comment: Small point: in the second rule case, from $k \ge 2$ conclude $m \ge 1$ so $x \ge 0$ which is needed so that $x \in \mathbb{N}$ still.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Ok thank you for pointing that out. Could some please should me how to use complete induction to prove the other way?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what you need to prove is equivalent to: for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $2^m \in S$.  Now, observe that if $m$ is even then $2^m = (2^{m/2})^2$ and $m/2 < m$, except in the base case $m = 0$.  If $m$ is odd then $2^m = (2^{(m+1)/2})^2 / 2$ and $(m+1)/2 < m$ except in the base case $m = 1$.

Comment: What would the predicate be?

Comment: $P(m) = (2^m \in S)$.

Comment: So the predicate is $ \ P(n): 2^{n} \in S$. Now for the base case $ \ n = 0$ we have $ \ 2^{0} = 1$ which is not in $ \ S$?

Comment: $1 \in S$ because $2 \in S$ by the base case, so by the second recursive rule $\frac{2}{2} \in S$.

Comment: But shouldn't the base case show that $ 2 \in S$ ?

Comment: There's no reason the base case in the definition of $S$ would have to correspond to the base case for proving $(\forall m \in \mathbb{N}) (2^m \in S)$ by induction.

Comment: So my base case would be $ n = 1$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65571/discussion-between-daniel-schepler-and-josh-mitkitzel).

Comment: When I see something I find interesting I jump on it and sometimes miss the fact that another answer provides the salient details. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Your proof $S \subset T$ is OK, but just one nit-picking point. You tagged the question with proof-writing, so it would be better to define the predicate $P(n)$ as

$\tag 1 \text{There exist a natural number } m \; \; | \; \; n = 2^m$

To show  $T \subset S$, observe that both $2^0$ and $2^1$ are in $S$. Define define $Q(n) \; \; n \gt 1$ as

$\tag 2 \text{For every } k \lt n  \;  \;  \; 2^k \in S$

Assume (2) is true. We must show that  $2^n \in S$.

If $n$ is even, $2^{\frac{n}{2}}$ must be in $S$. By applying the first recursion 
rule, $2^n$ is also in $S$.

If $n$ is odd $2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}$ must be in $S$. By applying the first recursion 
rule followed by the second recursion rule, $2^n$ is also in $S$.

Comment: I see now that my answer is an elaboration of Daniel's answer, but since the question was tagged 'proof-writing' and asked on September 11, this answer should add something to assisting the OP.